# Hide DataPager if Pages = 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How do I hide the DataPager if there is only one page of data?

In the DataPager events I have a `asp:Button` when clicked it gets records.

Sometimes there will be only one record and I need to hide the pager if there is one record.

It could be done on postback but I don't know what property is for the page count.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a blog article on MSDN that covers this topic:

[How to hide a DataPager control when there is only one page of data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mairaw/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-hide-a-datapager-control-when-there-is-only-one-page-of-data.aspx)

> One way of achieving this is to change the visibility of the control
>   on the DataBound event of the ListView control. For example:
>
> ```
> protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   DataPager1.Visible = (DataPager1.PageSize < DataPager1.TotalRowCount);
> }
> ```
>
> In the example above, the DataPager is not inside the ListView
>   control. If you place the DataPager inside the LayoutTemplate, then
>   you have to tweak the code a little bit to find the control inside
>   ListView. For example:
>
> ```
> protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   DataPager pager = (DataPager) ListView1.FindControl("DataPager1");
>   pager.Visible = (pager.PageSize < pager.TotalRowCount);
> }
> ```